# What's the name of this small purple eggplant cultivar?

Tags: identification, eggplant, cultivar

What's the name of this small purple eggplant cultivar?
The purple color is close to the purple of the Japanese eggplant and [Orient Charm eggplant](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/13/Orient_Express_and_Orient_Charm_eggplants_2017_C.jpg/800px-Orient_Express_and_Orient_Charm_eggplants_2017_C.jpg).

The ones in the first photo are 7 to 10 cm long, while in the second picture, they are about 10 to 13 cm long.

[image: Small]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the neon eggplant or *Solanum melongena*:
[image]

Description:
Neon
60–65 days. Deep pink 3–4" fruits. Good flavor, and does well in cooler, short summer climates where most eggplant varieties don't grow.

Meaty fruits to roast, fry, or bake in a range of cuisines.